# How to convert a list of elements into a list with 0 or 1

Tags: python

I have a list whose elements are either a json object or None. What would be the most elegant way to convert it into a list of 0's and 1's. For example here is my input :

```
mylist = [j1, j2, None, j3, None]
```

j1, j2, j3 are json objects. The expected output is

```
output_list = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

I can implement this using a for loop followed by if statement. Is there a way to do it which is more elegant/pythonic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and a [conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/2555451):

```
mylist[:] = [0 if x is None else 1 for x in mylist]
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> mylist = ['a', 'b', None, 'c', None]
>>> mylist[:] = [0 if x is None else 1 for x in mylist]
>>> mylist
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
>>>
```

The `[:]` will make it so that the list object is kept the same:

```
>>> mylist = ['a', 'b', None, 'c', None]
>>> id(mylist)
34321512
>>> mylist[:] = [0 if x is None else 1 for x in mylist]
>>> id(mylist)
34321512
>>>
```

Comment: Great answer. Perhaps even: `mylist[:] = [0 if x else 1 for x in mylist]` if you are interested in the general truthiness as opposed to only `None`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function on your list, here's a python shell's session:

```
>>> l = ['j1', 'j2', None, 'j3', None]
>>> map(lambda e : e is None, l)
[False, False, True, False, True]
>>> map(lambda e : e is not None, l)
[True, True, False, True, False]
>>> map(lambda e : int(e is not None), l)
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```